# Route VPN Connections through VPN

Tags: openvpn, openwrt, network-interface, pptp

I am currently setting up a wireless router using OpenWRT. The landlord of the dorm I live in requires joining a VPN to access the internet, supporting both PPTP and OpenVPN.

I want to support the "freifunk" network, which provides free WiFi all over Germany. As far as I was able to tell, due to the topology of that network and the legal circumstances here, every router connects to other routers using OpenVPN. I was wondering if it is possible to instruct the freifunk OpenVPN instance to use the PPTP VPN network interface ppp0 providing internet access and if it is possible, how to achieve this on openWRT.

Any help, including pointers to related articles would be greatly appreciated since my first searches found only articles telling windows users not to run several VPN clients at once. Since VPN clients in Linux create network interfaces, I could imagine it is possible to "chain" these together.

Comment: hmmmm.....have you considered using the route command on your system concerning various network address ranges?  BTW, I am assumming Linux.

Comment: Which regional Freifunk community do you wish to join? All Freifunk installations I know about access the "internal net" over a non-OpenVPN tunnel, either `fastd` (user space) or L2TP (kernel). If you are living in Germany, I am also a bit confused that you "have to use a VPN to access the Internet". Could you edit the question and provide more details? I suspect the answer is "you don't need VPN, Freifunk will tunnel and encrypt for you".

Comment: Unfortunately, it is indeed required that I use a VPN, because our LAN will only allow connections to the VPN server, where we have to authenticate.

Comment: Anyways, I don't consider this question relevant to myself anymore, since I have since moved out of that dorm. However, "tunneling VPN through VPN" could be relevant for other users as well, I guess.